# Taylor Remainder for Even, Bell-shaped Functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion

Given a function $f$ and its Taylor series. I'm looking for an easy-to-compute upper bound for Taylor's remainder. The missing term in Taylor series serves as an upper bound if they are alternating series. However, when $f$ is an even non-negative bell-shaped function, all coefficients of odd powers are 0. It's impossible to have an alternating Taylor series. In this case, I wonder intuitively how the Taylor series approaches $f$. Does it have to be true that all coefficients are non-negative? What does it look like geometrically? Does the Taylor Remainder have a convenient upper bound? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $e^{-x^2}$ is an even, positive, bell-shaped function, but is defined as

$e^{-x^2}:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{k!}$

and since power series is Taylor series, our function has an alternating Taylor series, with nice upper bounds.
The implication:
$\text{the coefficients of odd powers of x are 0}\implies \text{the Taylor Series is not alternating}$

is just wrong